# Drobo asking to replace larger drive

Tags: hard-drive, drobo

I have a Drobo 5D with single drive redundancy as follows:

4TB 4TB 8TB 8TB 8TB

The array is 95% full and it is asking me to replace a drive to get more space.  I would have expected it to ask me to replace one of the 4TB drives but in fact one of the 8TB is displaying the amber LED indicating replacement.  Additionally the health of that drive is listed as "Warning."

This drive has been in "Warning" state for a long time.  When I inquired with Drobo in the past they stated:

> Warning
>
> This message appears when a drive encounters block errors during an IO
>   operation.
>
> This does not mean your drive needs to be replaced, Drobo will blink
>   the drive bay Red if action is required.

It seems like a waste to replace the big 8TB drive with a larger drive.  Because of the way that the redundancy works I'll need to replace at least one additional drive in order to get additional space.

Must I replace the drive that Drobo recommends?  Or should/can I safely replace one of the 4TB drives?

Comment: “This does not mean your drive needs to be replaced, Drobo will blink the drive bay Red if action is required.” - This is false; Goes against Drobo’s own online documentation.  You will have to resolve the disk errors before you add a larger disk (you will have to replace it with more than 8 GB if you want any additional data storage).  I have been a drobo owner for years.

Answer (score 1):

When a drive is throwing block I/O errors, unplug/replug the drive and the cable(s) which connect it to the Drobo motherboard. If errors persist, yes, it is [replacement time](https://www.google.com/search?q=8TB%20SATA&tbm=shop).

Comment: Thanks. How would I know if “errors persist”?   Pulling and reseating the drive doesn’t reset the warning indicator I don’t believe...